# jQuery scrollTo-plugin not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scrollto

Got another one today,

So I implemented [the jQuery scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plug-in yesterday, and all is working fine in Chrome, Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox. Console-logging is enabled - no errors displayed.
It seems the function for scrolling does execute, but I don't see any scrolling happening.

Tested it with Firefox 28.0 under OpenSUSE 12.3 and Firefox 34.0 under Windows 8.0.

Here's my code so far:
HTML

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.navLink').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr('href');

        if( target.length ) {
            if( $("html, body").scrollTo(target, { offset: -128, duration: 750, easing: "easeOutCirc" }) ) {
                console.log("scrolling...");
            } else {
                console.log("I had ONE job...");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="navLink" href="#home">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="navLink" href="#info">INFO</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="navLink" href="#pics">PICS</a>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</nav>

<section id="home">
    <!-- stuff -->
</section>

<section id="info">
    <!-- stuff -->
</section>

<section id="pics">
    <!-- stuff -->
</section>
```

I saw a similar question on here (can't find the URL atm) where it was discovered an adblocker / security addOn / plug-In was causing this issue for the OP. There's no such addOns / plug-ins installed in my testing browsers.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.navLink').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        if( target.length > 0 ) {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 128
            }, 750);
        }
    });
});
```